# mongoskin inserts two records instead of one

Tags: mongodb, mongoskin

I'm new here and new to mongo etc and I'm having a strange problem I need help with.

I have created an app.js file which I'm running with node.  It listens for a web request and calls a function to write a record into mongodb using the mongoskin driver.  It kind of works but for some reason it inserts two records into mongodb rather than one.

I realise the code is not a good design and it's hard coded at the moment because I'm just trying to understand how it joins up and works together at this stage.  Anyway here is the code in my app.js:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end( hello() );
}).listen(3000, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:3000/');

function hello()
{
    // test mongodb and mongoskin driver
    var msg = "";
    var db = require('mongoskin').db('localhost:27017/mydb'); 

    db.collection('users').insert({site: "test.com", email: "fredbloggs@gmail.com", firstname: "Fred", lastname: "Bloggs", password: "hello"}, 
        function(err, result) {
            if (err) msg = "fail";
            if (result) msg="success";
        });

    return msg; 
}
```

I had some trouble with my original installation and wonder if I might have installed mongo twice or something like that?  Is it possible that two mongo instances are receiving my request and pointing at the same database?  Bit tenuous probably, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks
Kelly.

Comment: (Old post, I know). If you're hitting your server from a web browser, perhaps the second request is for the favicon? Since you don't distinguish requests, check the network tab in your browser and you'll probably see it is sending 2 requests.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're just starting, you may want to work with the [native driver](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native), instead of mongoskin.  Or at least test your config with it.  Mongoskin is built on the native driver and both are being actively developed, so it may be really easy to fall prey to a version skew issue.  Once you're comfortable with the native driver, and need the convenience of the future pattern, then you should be able to switch easily to mongoskin.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Here is a simple use of the driver with your example. Notice that we connect once to the db using MongoClient each request to the web server will now reuse the connection pool.

```
var   http = require('http');
    , MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb", function(err, db) {

  http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    hello(res);
  }).listen(3000, '127.0.0.1');

  console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:3000/');

  function hello(res) {
    // test mongodb and mongoskin driver
    db.collection('users').insert({
        site: "test.com"
      , email: "fredbloggs@gmail.com"
      , firstname: "Fred"
      , lastname: "Bloggs"
      , password: "hello" }, function(err, result) {
        var msg;

        if(err) msg = "fail";
        if(result) msg="success";

        res.end(msg);
      });
  }
})
```